# Input Numbers and Unit Grades Only at Textbox (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

Hi I Just Want to Input 1 to 5 only as unit grades on textbox
i use this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox16_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox16.TextChanged
    If TextBox16.Text >= 5 Then
        TextBox16.clear()
        MsgBox("Unit Grades Only From 1 to 5")

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

error came up:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: a) give your controls meaningful names - were you named "Child16" or some such?  b) turn on option strict - comparing text to a number is invalid because strings are not numbers.  Rather than monitoring every keystroke, lighten up and check all the inputs when they are done and click OK or whatever.  You dont need to scold them for a typo

Comment: If they are only supposed to enter 1-5 (integer) for something, use a NumericUpDown

Comment: If Integer.Parse(TextBox16.Text) >= 5 Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright you have two ways to do this:
**Preventing Typing Them**
In this case, you will deny user from typing other characters. So code this:

```
Private Sub TextBox16_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox16.KeyPress
'Deny user from entering more than one charecter
    TextBox1.MaxLength = 1
    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ,vbBack 'vbBack is backspace
            'You can enter any number that you whant
            e.Handled = False
        Case Else
            'Ignore the key
            e.Handled = True
            'Play a Beep sound.
            Beep()
        End Select
End Sub
```

or

**Checking With TextChanged**
Type in this in your method:

```
Dim textbox_val As Integer
'The user may enter alphabetical characters
Try
    textbox_val = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Unit Grades Only From 1 to 5")
    Exit Sub
End Try
If textbox_val >= 5 Then
    TextBox1.Clear()
    MsgBox("Unit Grades Only From 1 to 5")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your heart set on using a textbox for this , the following code should prevent any besides a 1 through 5 in the textbox. I used a textbox with a bit better naming txtUnitGrade.

```
Private _sLastValidValue As String = String.Empty
Private _bIgnoreChange As Boolean = False

Private Sub txtUnitGrade_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnitGrade.TextChanged

If Not _bIgnoreChange Then
    If txtUnitGrade.Text = String.Empty Then
        _sLastValidValue = String.Empty
    Else
        If Not IsNumeric(txtUnitGrade.Text) Then
            SetValueToLast()
        Else
            Dim iParsedValue As Integer = Integer.MinValue
            If Not (Integer.TryParse(txtUnitGrade.Text, iParsedValue)) OrElse iParsedValue < 0 OrElse iParsedValue > 5 Then
                SetValueToLast()
            Else
                _sLastValidValue = txtUnitGrade.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetValueToLast()
    Beep() 'you could add some other audible or visual cue that an block occured
    _bIgnoreChange = True
    txtUnitGrade.Text = _sLastValidValue
    txtUnitGrade.SelectionStart = txtUnitGrade.Text.Length
    _bIgnoreChange = False
End Sub
```